Prove the acute trigonometry inequality
Prove that in an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$,
$$\frac{\sin A\sin B}{\sin C}+\frac{\sin B\sin C}{\sin A}+\frac{\sin C\sin A}{\sin B}>\frac{5}{2}.$$
I know that the limit when equality holds is the isosceles right triangle. However, I have no idea how to deal with such problems for the wierd equality-hold condition.
I tried the product-to-difference formula but I couldn't place the "$\cot$" term in a right position.

Note that your inequality is equivalent $L = \frac{xy}{z} + \frac{yz}{x} + \frac{xz}{y} > \frac{5}{2}$, with $x= \sin A, y = \sin B$ and $z = \sin C$. Then by AM-GM, $L^3 \geq 27xyz$. Could you find a lower bound for $xyz$ in an acute triangle?

@Kraken It is sad to notice that $xyz$ can only be no more than something (lower bound is $0$), which means that the inequality had unfortunately gone to the other direction.

Oh, I thought perhaps it will workout

See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h599340

@nguyenhuyenag Thanks! That was amazing!
